# VM doesn't start (Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed)

Tags: virtual-machine

When I want to start a VirtualMachine (Fedora) I get the following Error.

```
Für die virtuelle Maschine My Fedora konnte keine neue Sitzung eröffnet werden.

Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Fehlercode: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Komponente: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I already deactivated Hyper-V which seems to be one the most frequent reasons for this problem, but the error still occurs.
Are there any other possible reasons?
The VM worked properly, I didn't change anything, then the error occured when I wanted to start it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues recently and solved it by following below steps -

1. Downloads [Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337)

2. Extract the file

3. Run Windows Power Shell as Administrator (maybe you can use command prompt but i did it on power shell)
4. cd to unzipped folder location (e.g. C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Compressed\dgreadiness_v3.6\dgreadiness_v3.6) - for my case
5. run this command `.\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot`

E.g.(`PS C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Compressed\dgreadiness_v3.6\dgreadiness_v3.6> .\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot`)

Notes: Make sure to deactivate Windows Sandbox at Windows features to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual box started working after I disabled [_] Windows Subsystem for Linux in "Windows Features". See the snapshot below.

[image: Turn Windows features on or off]

Answer (score 0):

I was having exact same problem and these steps helped me :

1. Run cmd as admin
2. Execute `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
3. Restart computer